# TypeError: points.filter is not a function when updating leaflet D3 v4 to v5

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

Wondering how to convert the following from D3 to v3 to v5 for use with Leaflet maps?

```
d3.csv('your.csv', function(d) {
        return {
            postcode: d.postcode,
            lat: +d.lat,
            lon: +d.lon,
            count: +d.count
        };
    }, function(error, rows) {
        points = rows;
        draw();
        map.on('viewreset moveend', draw);
    });
```

While this may seem to be a duplicate, the other answer did not appear when searching for the "points.filter" error.  The solution below applies to Martin Chorley’s map point sample:
https://bl.ocks.org/martinjc/7d8f64fbc586861a3c1d533c006f6099

Answer (score 0):

Here's the D3.js v5 update

```
   d3.csv("leaflet/postcode_data.csv").then(function(d) {
      // Using v5 data is whole data set:
      points = d;
      draw();
      map.on('viewreset moveend', draw);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      // handle error   
      alert("error: " + error)
    })
```